# How can I check Cronjob is working and make it work?

Tags: cron

I setup cronjob on server's crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1

30 3 * * * php /home/users/mydomain/www/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

it seems working on server

```
[root@ /var/log]# grep '/home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php' cron

May 10 16:00:01 crond[21592]: (root) CMD (/home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 10 16:05:01 crond[21718]: (root) CMD (/home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1)
May 10 16:10:01 crond[21766]: (root) CMD (/home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1)
```

but when I check the cron scheduler module I can see that cronjob is not working

> Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and
>   your configuration!

Both cronjob and scheduler works well before I moved my all files to other folders

How can I check Cronjob is working and make it work?

Comment: This might help you out. http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run cron job](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133306/how-to-run-cron-job)

Answer (score 6):

Take a view to your MySQL Database > table `cron_schedule`. There are all magento created jobs with timestamp of creation, scheduled, executed and their status.

If anything wrong, then look for the cron job in the table and see if there is any log in the `messages` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
*/5 * * * * sh /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Use cron.sh, not cron.php, which you will need php for.

Comment: This makes more sense to me than using cron.php, working on this now, I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: cron.sh is not supported. see: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check that whether your cron is scheduled or not, to check this run your cron, as cron runs it makes the entry in database, if you find that entry in your database that means your cron is scheduled correctly.

And  if it is scheduled correctly but not running, in this case there may be two possibilities- 
 First is you may have written the wrong file path where the cron has to be run, or 
You have made some mistakes on the piece of code where you have called the cron function. To check this you can apply the logger on that code  to find the error that why your cron is not working. As you apply the logger, it will make a log file  /var/log/ in the magento root directory   through which you can find the error.