# How to run cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cron, frontend

I want realise a cron job for import product in Magento. The code to insert the product into a php file saved in `app/code/local/Test/Import/Model`.

I saved `config.xml` in `app/code/local/Test/Import/etc`. I added module in `app/etc/modules`.

config.php contains following code:

```
<config>
     <modules>
        <Test_Import>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Test_Import>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <import>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Import</module> 
                    <frontName>import</frontName> 
                </args>
            </import>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <import>
                <class>Test_Import_Model</class>
            </import>
        </models>
    </global> 
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <import>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>import/observer::importProduct</model>
                </run>
            </import>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

When I try to run it the result is `404 PAGE NOT FOUND`.

Which is the correct url to run the cron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check Cronjob is working and make it work?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-can-i-check-cronjob-is-working-and-make-it-work)

Answer (score 6):

The cron jobs in Magento don't have an URL to run with.
To test it you have to wait the time you defined and ensure it is running.

Installing the module [AOE_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) can help you handling and debug them.

If you have the suspect your cron jobs are not executed, you can call manually the `example.com/cron.php` URL from the browser. But since the SUPEE-6788 security patch, this is forbidden by default and you have to add permissions in `.htaccess` first. See: [After applying SUPEE-6788 , cron stopped working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88335/after-applying-supee-6788-cron-stopped-working/88337#88337)

It's better to run

```
php /path/to/magento/cron.php -mdefault
```

on the command line

Comment: I installed Magento on Windows 7. Where is the file .htaccess? How can I change permissions? Many thanks!!

Comment: The .htaccess file is located in the Magento root folder. However, it might be  recognised as a hidden file and not shown in the file explorer. Try to open it via terminal (command line) or enable the visualisation of hidden files in Windows explorer.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to add Magento `cron.sh` file in crontab

`crontab -e`

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /path-to-magento/cron.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to server and setup your cronjob and `cron.sh` file in your severs cronjob

Then this all cronjobs that you define in crontab is working fine .

For how to add `cron.sh` file you can follow this post.

[Which cron script is best to run? cron.php or cron.sh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63707/which-cron-script-is-best-to-run-cron-php-or-cron-sh)

Answer (score 0):

**ADDING A NEW MAGENTO CRON TASK VIA CPANEL**

To set up a new `cron` task in Magento via cPanel, log into your site’s configuration panel at

`http://yourmagentosite.com:2082/` `or https://yourmagentosite.com:2083/`.

Then, enter `cron` into the search field, and you’ll see a Cron jobs option in the Advanced section.

[image: setup cron magento]

To set up a cron job with this method, you may need to enter an email address in the Cron email section. This email will be used to send cron messages to, which is useful in case of any cron job execution issues.

[image: setup cron magento]

Now let’s set the cron schedule and the command to be run.

[image: setup cron magento]

Press Add New Cron Job to finish your configuration.